# How can I protect user Data after login, even when URL changes (Next JS 13)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have started my first full-stack application using Nextjs.  I have implemented user login using Next-Auth to my Database.

My question is really about securing user data.  If I change my URL params, which includes the user ID, the original user data stays on the screen.  I saw something about checking the URL Id against the Session Id, is this Adequate? if so do I have to do this check on every page that needs it?

Because I am new to this I'm not even sure what keywords to search.

Does anyone have any topics that can help me lock down my application so that a user can only see their info.

thanks

Comment: You could use [jwt tokens](https://jwt.io/) in order to verify that its a "valid" user, and save the token as a cookie. The JWT token works by signing the token itself so you know the token hasn't been changed since you've generated it etc.